# Passing extra arguments to callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
websocketServer.on('connection', function(socket, req) {
  socket.on('message', onMessage);

  sub.subscribe('chat'); // sub: Redis subscription connection
  sub.on('message', onSubMessage);
});

function onMessage(message) {
  pub.publish('chat', message); // pub: Redis publishing connection
}

function onSubMessage(channel, message) {
  // how to access 'socket' from here?
  if (channel === 'chat') socket.send(message);
}
```

I'm trying to get away with as few state & bindings as possible, to make WS server efficient & to have the ability to just add more machines if I need to scale - state would only make this harder. Im still not understanding everything about Node memory management & garbage collection.

What would be the recommended solution in this case? Move `onSubMessage` into `connection` callback to access `socket`? But function would be then initialized on every connection?

What other choices do I have?

---

#### Little background about this:

The user opens a WebSocket connection with the server. If the user sends a message, it gets sent to Redis channel (might also know it as Pub/Sub topic) which broadcasts it to every subscribed client (`onSubMessage`). Redis Pub/Sub acts as a centralized broadcaster: I don't have to worry about different servers or state, Redis sends a message to everybody who is interested. Carefree scaling.

Comment: How about wrapping the event: `sub.on('message', function (channel, message) { onSubMessage(channel, message, socket); });`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis That was my first instinct too but then I found [this](https://github.com/uNetworking/bindings/blob/master/nodejs/examples/echo.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pre-define an extra argument to the callback function:

```
...
sub.on('message', onSubMessage.bind(sub, socket));
...

function onSubMessage(socket, channel, message) {
  if (channel === 'chat') socket.send(message);
}
```

This *does* create a new function instance for every new connection, so there is probably not a real upside to using a wrapping function in terms of memory usage.

Comment: I guess I have to test it with high traffic because I have no idea what it `exactly` does & how it affects memory. Im trying to get around [this](https://github.com/uNetworking/bindings/blob/master/nodejs/examples/echo.js) problem or at least perform better.

Comment: @Solo there isn't going to be a better solution, though. You need to get `socket` into your handler, which means either binding, wrapping or moving the entire handler inside the `connection` handler.

Comment: Thanks, I have to accept the reality then. Some better than others?

Comment: @Solo you'd have to test, I wouldn't know which one would perform better.